# How To Create Or design popUp windows for Edit ro Insert

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

i'm startter in jQgrid plugin in asp.net, i'm desing Grid andd fill Grid in data,Now I'm going to use this feature to add, edit, add and edit information on how to design????
thanks all.

Comment: I had started to edit the question, but the end result would have been altogether different. **I'm a starter in jqGrid plugin in asp.net. I'm designing Grid and filling data in it. Now I want to use the feature to add or edit records. How should I design this?
Thanks All.** I am going to down-vote this. If you don't know programming please at least learn some communication skills.

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot I rushed because I was so sorry I did not check the terms of the literature

Comment: Do you tried the standard [form editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing)? You can add the Add/Edit/Delete buttons in the pager with respect of call of [navGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:navigator). What kind of customization you need to do? Do you really need to redesign the dialogs?

Comment: @Oleg --- I do not want to re-design just now when I click on the Add button opens a blank page,I Just Want Add example TextBox or DropDown,.. in blank page.

Comment: jqGrid include in the Add/Edit forms *only columns having `editable: true` property* (see [the documantation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules)).

Comment: @Oleg-- Thanks,I have a question, How can I correct the alignment of the control layout just is not true that they are not aligned?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the jqGrid "[My First Grid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3afirst_grid)" walk-through.  It's well-done and shows you the basics of using jqGrid.  Once you're cool with this, the [demos page](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) will show you all sorts fo CRUD abilities.

Comment: I Fill Data in jqGrid, but i want design popup window for insert or update, thanks

Comment: On the jqGrid demos page, look at the "Live Data Manipulation" -> "Edit Row" demo.  It will show you how to integrate a modal popup to edit a row of the grid.  You'll want to look at the source of the page to see everything that's going on.